# How to find highest average score in a class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to display the maximum average score in a class; however, I have been battling with the query for hours now and can't seem to get it to work.

I can get a list of the average scores of students to display, with:

```
   public function GetSumAvgftScore($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select_avg('ft_tot_score');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        return $this->db->get('ftscores_primary')->row(); 
    }
```

However, I get stuck when I try to display the highest average score. This is what I've tried:

```
  public function GetHighestClassAvg($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->order_by('ft_tot_score', 'DESC');
        $this->db->select_max(avg('ft_tot_score'));
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $data = $this->db->get('ftscores_primary')->row(); 
    }
```

This doesn't give me anything.

Comment: This `$this->db->where('student_id', $session_id);` is either a typo in your question or the likely cause of your problem?

Comment: I rectified it, now I get the error `Message: Call to undefined function avg()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function GetHighestClassAvg($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->order_by('ft_tot_score', 'DESC');
        $this->db->select_avg('ft_tot_score');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $data = $this->db->get('ftscores_primary')->row(); 
    }
```

Comment: This is still giving me the average scores of students. I want to pick out the highest average.

Comment: The average will be the same number, what is the point to the Max

Comment: Its to be displayed in the students' result sheet. A student's average score will be shown on his sheet, so also will the highest average score in that class.

Comment: In that case, select the Max from the result of this given query. with LIMIT

$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
$myRow = $query->row();
with OFFSET and LIMIT

$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 0, 1);
$myRow = $query->row();

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not give me the highest avg